# How to get non-bar SHAP plot for LightGBM

Tags: python, plot, lightgbm, shap

I have trained a lightGBM model using this code:

```
from flaml import AutoML    
#Select Hyper-Parameters
automl_final = AutoML()
automl_final.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    estimator_list=["lgbm"],#,"xgboost"], 
    task="classification",
    metric="roc_auc",
    eval_method="cv",
    n_splits=3,
    time_budget=30,
    sample=True,
    append_log=True,
    log_type="all",
    model_history=True,
    log_training_metric=True,
    verbose=3,
    seed=1234,
    early_stop=True
)
```

Then I have generated a SHAP bar plot using this code:

```
lgbm = automl_final.model.estimator
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(lgbm)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test,plot_type="bar")
```

And I got this plot (as expected):

[image]

Now, I would like to see a SHAP plot like the following one:

[image]

So I have used this code instead:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

And I still get the same SHAP bar-chart plot as before:

[image]

Does anybody know how to generate a plot similar to this one (for lightgbm - for xgboost the code works fine):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
shap.plots.beeswarm(shap_values)
```

Please check the [documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/beeswarm.html) if needed.

Comment: I think the question was fair based on the documentation : https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.summary_plot.html. in this link you will see that there is not much explanation about how to switch between beeswarm and barplots with the summary-plot() function.  @Austin and other commentators bellow offer useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have trained a classification model, running `shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)` will return an array with two sets of shap values for predicting each of class=0 and class=1. This is why when you run `shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)` you get a bar chart with two bars for class=0 and class=1. To get a beeswarm summary plot of shap values for the prediction of class=1, you run:

`shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)`

That will give you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For a binary class lgbm model, use the shap values for one class to generate plot -

```
lgbm = automl_final.model.estimator
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(lgbm)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)
```